# Test_bench in Verilog using Task

Tags: verilog

I have written testbench in verilog. All the test cases define in task works independently well but when I try to run both task then it give proper output for 1st task in task_operation but not for other task. The stimulus remain there for another task also. I want to use input in task as locally instead of globally define. How should I define input in argument in task so that input should be given independently?

```
module tb();
  reg data_i_t;
  reg dcsel_t;
  reg clk ;
  reg reset_t;
  reg reset;
  reg read_t;
  reg xlat_t;

  initial begin
#2 reset =0;
task_operation();
#100000 $finish;
  end

  task task_operation();

    begin
      exp_case_2a(data_i_t,reset_t,read_t,dcsel_t,xlat_t,data_out_1);    
  exp_case_2b(data_i_t,reset_t,read_t,dcsel_t,xlat_t,data_out_1);       
    end
  endtask 

  task exp_case_2a;
    input data_i;
    input reset;
    input read;
    input dcsel;
    input xlat;     
    output reg [47:0] data_o;
    begin
      repeat(47) begin @(posedge clk)
    data_i = 1;
    reset   = 0;
    read = 1;
    dcsel = 0;
    xlat = 1;
    data_o = Data_out;
      end
      #5250  compare_data_2(data_out_tb);    
    end 
  endtask 

  task exp_case_2b
    input data_i;
    input reset;
    input read;
    input dcsel;
    input xlat;     
    output reg [47:0] data_o;
    begin
      repeat(47)begin @(posedge clk)
        data_i = 1;
        reset  = 0;
        read   = 0;
        dcsel  = 0;
        xlat   = 1;
        data_o = Data_out;          
      end
      #5250 compare_data_2(data_out_tb);
    end 
  endtask
```

/* ...........  SCORE-BOARD..............
   task compare_data_2;
      input [47:0] exp_data;

```
  begin        
 if(exp_data == `comp_data_1 )
   begin
       `INFO("TEST PASSSED",$time);
      $display(" exp_data  : %h ",exp_data);
   end
 else
   begin
       `ERROR("TEST FAILED",$time);
      $display(" exp_data : %h ",exp_data); 
   end 
  end
```

endtask

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could clarify this statement :

> How should I define input in argument in task so that input should be given independently?

A task defined as:

```
task display_redux
  input [31:0] a_number;
  begin
    $display("display_redux was sent : %d", a_number);
  end
endtask
```

Can be called with :

```
display_redux(20);
integer ii = 6;
display_redux(ii);
```

To me the input here is independent from anything else, and you can not assign value to the input so it does not have side effects from of modifying inputs from where it was called.

Taking one of your tasks:

```
task exp_case_2b
  input data_i;
  input reset;
  input read;
  input dcsel;
  input xlat;     
  output reg [47:0] data_o;
  begin
    repeat(47)begin @(posedge clk)
      data_i = 1;
      reset  = 0;
      read   = 0;
      dcsel  = 0;
      xlat   = 1;
      data_o = Data_out;          
    end
    #5250 compare_data_2(data_out_tb);
  end 
endtask
```

Youve declared many inputs which you are not driving when you call it with `exp_case_2b(data_out)`. You have defined inputs then are trying to drive values on to them. You need these to be `reg`s and not inputs so they are local to the task. Or not defined at all and use hierarchical references to the top level reset, aka `tb.reset = 0;`.

I think this might have been what you were trying todo:

```
task exp_case_2b
  input      [47:0] data_i;     
  output reg [47:0] data_o;
  begin
    repeat(47)begin @(posedge clk)
      data_i = 1;
      reset  = 0;
      read   = 0;
      dcsel  = 0;
      xlat   = 1;
      data_o = Data_out;          
    end
    #5250 compare_data_2(data_out_tb); //No idea where this variable comes from
  end 
endtask
```

Then call :

```
 exp_case_2a(data_i_t, data_out_1);
```

Comment: initial 
       begin
   //inialize inputs
   #1 rst=1;
   #2 rst =0;     
   exp_case_2a(data_out_1);
   exp_case_2b(data_out_1);
  #100000 $finish;
       end